# increase edge length

Tags: tikz-trees

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[every tree node/.style={draw,circle},edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode)},baseline]
\Tree [.\node(first) [draw, align=center] {\textbf{A} \\ \textit{\footnotesize{100 }}};
        \node(second) [draw, align=center] {\textbf{B} \\ \textit{\footnotesize{20 }}};
        \node(third) [draw, align=center, fill=orange] {\textbf{C} \\ \textit{\footnotesize{40 }}};
        \node(fourth) [draw, align=center] {\textbf{D} \\ \textit{\footnotesize{35 }}};
      ]
\begin{scope}[xshift=3in,every tree node/.style={},edge from parent path={}]
\end{scope}
\node[below]at(current bounding box.south){\textbf{Figura 2. Exemplo de Árvore Resultante}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

How do i increase the edge length from A to C?

[image]

Comment: Please post complete minimal code rather than a fragment.

Comment: Actually thats all i have.
Before and after the tikzpicture i have only text

Comment: @Guilherme cfr was referring to packages, any relevant options in the preamble for Tikz trees and of course, the document class.

Comment: O sorry. Im using this two packages: tikz and tikz-qtree

Comment: @Guilherme Include them in the question. The code in there should be compilable so that we just need to copy/paste it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the edges length by changing the `sibling distance`. Also, `left=, right=, above=, below=` can be used.

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[every tree node/.style={draw,circle}, level 1/.style={sibling distance=20mm},level 2/.style={sibling distance=20mm},edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode)},baseline
]
\Tree [.\node(first) [draw, align=center] {\textbf{A} \\ \textit{\footnotesize{100 }}};
        \node(second) [draw, align=center] {\textbf{B} \\ \textit{\footnotesize{20 }}};
        \node(third) [draw, align=center, fill=orange,below=7mm] {\textbf{C} \\ \textit{\footnotesize{40 }}};
        \node(fourth) [draw, align=center] {\textbf{D} \\ \textit{\footnotesize{35 }}};
      ]
\begin{scope}[xshift=3in,every tree node/.style={},edge from parent path={}]
\end{scope}
\node[below]at(current bounding box.south){\textbf{Figura 2. Exemplo de Árvore Resultante}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

[image]