# With Tikz Tree how can I make two nodes grow up while the rest grow down?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

This is my first use of Tikz. I have a Tikz Tree using this code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={minimum width=2em,draw,circle},
            blank/.style={draw=none}, 
            edge from parent/.style=
            {draw,edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode)}},
            level distance=1.5cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree
    [.c
        \edge[]; [.a 
        ]
        \edge[]; [.b
        ]
        \edge[]; [.d 
            \edge[]; {d1}
            \edge[]; {d2}
        ]
        \edge[]; [.e
            \edge[]; {e1}
            \edge[]; {e2}
        ]
    ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This gives me;

[image: This tree]

What I would like is to have 'a' above-left of 'c' and 'b' above-right, while the rest of the tree grows down as normal.

I've been poking around for Tikz examples, but haven't found one that looks as I would like.  All advice welcome. Thanks.

=== Second iteration

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
    \tikzset{every tree node/.style={minimum width=2em,draw,circle},
                blank/.style={draw=none}, 
                edge from parent/.style=
                {draw,edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode)}},
                level distance=1.5cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \Tree
        [.c
            \edge[]; \node(first) [draw, align=left, above=28mm, left=14mm] {\textbf{a}};
            \edge[]; \node(second) [draw, align=right, above=28mm, right=14mm] {\textbf{b}};
            \edge[]; [.d 
                \edge[]; {d1}
                \edge[]; {d2}
            ]
            \edge[]; [.e
                \edge[]; {e1}
                \edge[]; {e2}
            ]
        ]
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Give me almost what I want, but 'a' and 'b' are squished to the left.

[image: squished left]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Does [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311240) question help?

Comment: @jessexknight, Thank you!  I added a bit to my example, and got 'a' and 'b' above 'c', but `align` didn't get 'b' to move to the right of 'c'.  Got another hint?

Comment: @jessexknight - also added `left=` and `right=`, but they didn't change the position relative to 'c', but it does move 'c'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**
[Here is a more general solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/643061/125871).

Here is a solution using `forest`, which is somewhat more flexible than `qtree`. You can add manual adjustments to the individual nodes by using `before drawing tree`. You can add or subtract to the `x` or `y` coordinates by using `y±=<length>,x±=<length>`, or set the coordinates with `y=<coordinate>,x=<coordinate>`.

I was unclear if you also wanted the `d` and `e` subtrees to be shifted so they are symmetric with respect to the `c` node.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={draw,circle,minimum width=2em,anchor=center}
[c
    [a,before drawing tree={y=1cm,x=-1cm}]
    [b,before drawing tree={y=1cm,x=1cm}]
    [d
        [d1]
        [d2]]
    [e
        [e1]
        [e2]]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

For a more flexible solution, in case the `a` and `b` nodes have nonempty subtrees, you can create two empty children for the `c` node and set their `grow` directions. But before computing the position of the empty children, use `before computing xy={l=0,s=0}` to place the empty nodes at the root. The syntax `if level=1{<do this>}{<else do this>}` can be placed in the main `for tree`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={minimum width=2.5em, anchor=center, circle,
    if level=1{no edge, before computing xy={l=0,s=0}}{draw}}
[c
[, for tree={grow'=north}
    [a[a1][a2]]
    [b[b1][b2]]]
[, 
    [d
        [d1]
        [d2]]
    [e
        [e1]
        [e2]]]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sandy, Thanks!  I prefer the more symmetric version, so I copied the bottom example. It works, but does give a warning, "Returning node center instead of a point on node border. Did you specify a point identical to the center of node node@3?"  Do you know how to squash that?

Comment: @CAB: Yes. I am aware of that warning. I fixed it in [this more general solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/643061/125871). I just added your example to that solution so you can see the code. You'll need to copy the `forestset` from that solution.